# Ruby on Rails -- How to create table of ALL logins/sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a working application for using Devise for user models and authentication. I want to create a table that effectively stores ALL the logins a user ever has, and the length of these sessions. I do not need to store session data with the entries. Am using the "timeoutable" option in Devise which I think will ensure I always have a logout time (?) even if a user just closes the browser window.

What I want is effectively the opposite (in some sense) of how the sessions table operates in only recording the latest user session when using active_record_store option in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

So what's needed is a logins table with `user_id` and `login_id/index` (plus login time and logout time) that is edited automatically any time a user logs in or out, and DOESN'T delete or overwrite the older sessions. Does this require a model, controller, etc. like other user-edited objects?

Answer is probably something simple, but I spent a lot of time looking and didn't see too many folks who actively want to store MORE user data like this. Thanks for any advice! [I'm a Prof. doing this for a basic web-course app so I can make student time on the site part a factor in their grade ;)]

Using rails 3.2.13, devise, sqlite3 for development db

Comment: Did you read my answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: Hi, yes--it was definitely helpful...just is taking me awhile to figure out how to use these as I'm pretty new to rails and I think what I wanted to do might be simpler than what these gems provide. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The advantage of those them is that they wrap up pretty much everything, you don't have to worry about how to write the code. But also once you know them you can get inspiration from their internal code and write your own. It's good when you start with Rails to use what's available in gems, it help for your learning curve. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can have a look at those 2 gems. They offer model data change tracking:

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited